# Dependence between Activity and createpdf function

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I'd like to create som pdf files in an android app.
I found a tutorial and it works fine, but...
I use my own function createPDF() in my Activity.
My question is: how can I use (for instance TextView tv1) to populate a paragraph by using the inner createPDF() function?

Some example code

```
public class GenPDF extends Activity {

     TextView tv1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.genpdf); 
                createPDF();        
        } 

public void createPDF()
        {
             Document doc = new Document();
             Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(//my text from textview goes here//);
             doc.add(p1);
            }
```

Just for example, how can I put some text from tv1 (which is a TextView) to Paragraph p1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like this should work for you. In the future, read the documentation for `TextView`, as it describes very well how to get its text contents.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
String textViewContents = textView.getText();
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(textViewContents);
doc.add(p1);
```